# `sudo ubuntu-drivers list` is suggesting a server version of the nvidia driver

Tags: 18.04, apt, nvidia, ubuntu-drivers

Today on Ubuntu 18.04.5 I tried to update the nvidia driver using `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` which led to the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-driver-450-server : Depends: libnvidia-gl-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-compute-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-extra-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-decode-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-encode-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: nvidia-utils-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-450-server (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Recommends: libnvidia-compute-450-server:i386 (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-decode-450-server:i386 (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-encode-450-server:i386 (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386 (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:i386 (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
                            Recommends: libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386 (= 450.51.06-0ubuntu0.18.04.2)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I then ran `sudo ubuntu-drivers list` and got the following output:

```
nvidia-driver-435
nvidia-driver-440-server
nvidia-driver-418-server
nvidia-driver-450-server
```

Anyone have any clue why it is trying to install a server version of the driver? I already have a normal nvidia driver installed and working fine.

Also, I noticed the following weirdness:
`sudo apt-cache depends nvidia-driver-440`
output:

```
nvidia-driver-440
  Depends: nvidia-driver-450
```

Why would an old driver depend on a new driver? Seems totally wrong to me. Is this NVidia's weird way of forcing people to upgrade their driver or something?

Comment: Good point, when I run `sudo apt install --fix-broken` however, everything seems fine. Removing and installing firefox goes smoothly. Running `dpkg -l | grep ^..r ` as suggested elsewhere in this forum also produces no issues.

Comment: I installed nvidia 450 from ppa and don't have this behavior. One  package installed in 440 version : it is the `nvidia-setting-440` package.
Did you install from ppa ?

Comment: By ppa, you mean a custom NVidia ppa? not the typical ubuntu main/universe ppas?
The only other ppa I have installed is `http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64` from [installing cuda](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation)

Comment: I mean this ppa : https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: Nope, I don't have that ppa on my "Other Software" tab in "Software & Updates". I have the main, universe, restricted, and multiverse sources enabled on the "Ubuntu Software" tab though.

Comment: Then you could try to install form this ppa. Last nvidia driver is 455.

Comment: See my complete answer below

Answer (score 0):

You tried to run the wrong command. The correct command to run is as follows:

```bash
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
sudo reboot
```

The `install` option of `ubuntu-drivers` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

The `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` error message could also be caused by a PPA that you have added to your software sources if `sudo apt ubuntu-drivers install` doesn't work.

Comment: `sudo apt ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` this is wrong, did you mean `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`? Regardless, the `install` and `autoinstall` verbs both seem to do the same thing.

Comment: It's not wrong and I did mean exactly `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. The `autoinstall` command of `ubuntu-drivers` selects and installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.For more information search Ask Ubuntu or Google for `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` or visit [How to install the NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know where why you have this this bug the the recommended installation is from the ppa.

Try to install the latest version from ppa :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Check the proposed drivers with :

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

If the 455 is the recommended version run :

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Alternatively, install desired driver selectively using the apt command. For example:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-450
```

If you have some trouble, purge the old installation before installing new driver :

```
$ sudo apt purge nvidia-*
```

Source : https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Comment: When I try to add the ppa:graphics-drivers it results in the following warning:
"This PPA is currently in testing, you should be experienced with packaging before you dive in here:", so I don't think I want to go there.

Anyway, thanks for your help! it seems like the best way to install nvidia drivers is with `sudo apt install nvidia-*`. I was hoping the ubuntu-drivers tool/command was mature enough to just install the latest driver without worrying about which version is latest (for scripting purposes), but maybe it's still too early to rely on it.